# Как открывать MainActivity при открытии свернутого приложения?

Tags: android, activity

Хочу чтоб каждый раз, когда приложение запускается, даже если оно свёрнуто, сразу открывалось MainActivity. Спасибо!

Comment: А сейчас что открывается?

Comment: То что было открыто до сворачивания

Comment: Читайте про жизненный цикл активности. onPause, onResume, onRestart и т.д.

Comment: Хотеть не вредно.

Answer (score 0):

Если задача стоит именно, чтоб при запуске приложения всегда стартовала главная активити. И если свернунуть и развернуть оставалось, то что было свернуто.
Наиболее правильно решить задачу с помощью атрибутов активити.
Почитайте про clearTaskOnLaunch
 https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element?hl=ru#clear

Вам в манифесте для вашей активити нужно поставить

```
  <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        ....
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
```